# UIPasteboard pastes non-retina image in keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm using UIPasteboard to copy and paste a retina image in a keyboard extension, but it displays as a non-retina image when pasted into notes or messages.

Below is my code that copies the image into pasteboard.

```
        UIImage *retinaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"retinaimage.png"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(retinaImage);
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:imageData forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```